# Gnuplot in overleaf with legends in latex language

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I want to generate an image in the gnuplottex of Overleaf, but I don't get to use the latex language. For example, if I make

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf, terminaloptions={font ",10" linewidth 3}]
set yrange[0:22]
set xrange[0:60]
set style line 1 dt 1    lw 8 lc rgb 'grey30'
set xlabel "{/Symbol s}" enhanced font ",15"
plot "dados.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps .5 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
\end{gnuplot}
```

this is the same thing that the gnuplot. But, if I want to use the latex language, I need to make

```
\begin{gnuplot}
set yrange[0:22]
set xrange[0:60]
set style line 1 dt 1    lw 8 lc rgb 'grey30'
set xlabel "$\sigma$" enhanced font ",15"
plot "dados.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps .5 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
\end{gnuplot}
```

But, the image isn't good, it don't have color and has some problems sometimes.

Doe someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'use the LaTeX language'? Do you mean you want the label text to have the same appearance as the rest of the document text?

Comment: Yes. All label text write in language of latex.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Overleaf account, but on my local LaTeX/gnuplot installation it works to use the `cairolatex` terminal:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]
   set title "Hello world!"
   set xlabel "Hello Maij!"
   plot sin(x) title '$\frac12$ nonsense'
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

In order to get the LaTeX command `$\frac12` to work, I had to use single quotes or I had to escape the backslash: `'$\frac12$'` or `"$\\frac12$"`, respectively.

I compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.

You can find more information on the gnuplottex package on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex), especially the [pdf documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf). There you can also find the terminal descriptions.